# Smooshing faces against each other: Making features coplanar, while preserving surrounding geometry

Tags: modeling, transforms, geometry, snapping

How can I make the base of the pyramid coplanar to (smooshed up against, so they are flat against each other) the slanted face of the wedge (pictured below)?

[image]

1. The objects and their origins need to stay the same.
2. If all of the pictured geometry were part of one object, and #1 was not a requirement, how could this be achieved? (If this were a mesh level transformation instead of an object level transformation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Multiple objects:

For this you can use [custom transform orientations](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Custom_Orientations) again:

1. Select the face and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>:

   [image]
2. In object mode, select the object you wish to align and press *Align to transform orientation* in *3D view > Header > Object > Transform*:

   [image]
3. Once the object is aligned, use transform snapping with *face* as the snapping element.

   If the bottom of the spike thing is already the closest face to the target, then *closest* should be fine as the snapping target. If not, use the 3D cursor trick as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18107/599).

   [image]

---

*I think you should be able to use transform snapping for rotation too, but for no apparent reason there is an inexplicable gap when snapping without a pre-aligned model..*

[image]

*I've [reported this as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T42362).*

---

## Single mesh:

A similar approach to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18108/599) can be used:

[image]

A custom transform orientation aligned to the target face will help too.