# Matching point locations: Relative translation, preserving surrounding geometry

Tags: modeling, geometry, snapping

How can I move the tip of the pyramid so that it sits at the top of Suzanne's ear (pictured below, the noted point is highlighted)?

[image]

1. The objects and their origins need to stay the same.
2. If all of the pictured geometry were part of one object, and #1 was not a requirement, how could this be achieved? (If this were a mesh level transformation instead of an object level transformation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multiple objects

This can be done with a combination of [transform snapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh#Transform_Snapping) and [3D cursor snapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh#Snap).

1. Snap the cursor the the point vertex by selecting it in edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to selected*:

   [image]
2. Set the [pivot point](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point) to *3D cursor* (<kbd>.</kbd>)
3. Set the *snap element* to *vertex* and the *snap target* to *Center* in *3D view > Header*:

   [image]
4. In object mode, grab the pointer object and move it over the target vertex while holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>:

   [image]

---

## Single mesh

If everything is in the same mesh, you don't even need to use the 3D cursor:

1. Select the geometry you want to move, making sure the vertex on the tip is *active* (last selected, appears white):

   [image]
2. Set the *snap target* to *Active*:

   [image]
3. Snap away by holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>.

   [image]

   Note that you can also enable snapping without holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> by clicking the magnet icon in *3D view > header*, then things will snap by default and holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> will make them *not* snap.