# How do I match an object's rotation based on the other object's face's rotation?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do I get this cylinder to match the rotation of the selected face?

I want to do something similar as shown in the 2nd image:

[image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/539/snap-object-on-top-of-surface-of-other-object/6002#6002

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18101/smooshing-faces-against-each-other-making-features-coplanar-while-preserving-s/18109#18109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the face you want the cylinder aligned to and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>. this will align the view to the face in a top down perspective.

Afterwards you can create a cylinder with the checkbox "align to view" selected.

In this case it is also good to know, that you can create a Custom Transformation orientation with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> while selecting the face.